# Google script for Alphavantage gives weird results

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, alpha-vantage

I am trying to make a google script which i want to use in Google sheets.
I followed a tutorial video on youtube and i had the idea that my script was working well.

But then two strange things happen, and i can't figure out why.
Below is my code, this code is exactly doing what i want.
It is showing the EPS of IBM in the google sheets and also in the log.
However the moment i change the APIkey from "demo" to my own APIkey it is not working anymore.
At that moment it is still showing the EPS in the LOG, but i will get an empty cell in Google Sheets.

I have no idea why that happens.

```
/**
 * Imports api data from alphavantage 
 * @customfunction
 */
function apiav(a) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo'
  );
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var overviewvalue = json['EPS'];
  Logger.log(overviewvalue);
  return overviewvalue;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the apikey in the URL doesn't matter. I tried accessing the URL and changed the apikey with some random numbers and the result is still the same with `demo`. Could you also include the part where you write the data to sheets?

Comment: Hi Nikko,
I go to sheets and put "=apiav("J")" in a cell. Where J is some random argument. 
When i use the demo apikey i get the result "8.823" with my own apikey it is blank.

There is no other code to include, this everything i have. 

The strange thing is that if i use both the links in my browser i get indeed exact the same web pages. So for me it is total unclear why the google sheets is not giving the same outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `{validateHttpsCertificates: false}` to your UrlFetchApp.fetch() to ignores any invalid certificates for HTTPS requests.

Your code should look like this:

```
function apiav(a) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=ABCDEFGH', {validateHttpsCertificates: false});
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var overviewvalue = json['EPS'];
  Logger.log(overviewvalue);
  return overviewvalue;
}
```

Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)