# Same Apps Script code provides a different output when called from the custom formula

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

Same Apps Script code provides a different output when called from the custom formula. I was trying to call an API and get the data from it. Initially, it worked just fine. Later it started producing errors. I've checked with the API limits and no limit is crossed. I've tested the code multiple times. But I got an error message every time I run the code from the custom formula. The other way it works just fine.

When I run the code from the editor, I get the below log:

```
res2 = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "rxt",
        "2: Indicator": "St.....
```

When I run the code from the custom formula, I get the below log:

```
res2 = {
    "Information": "Thank you for using.....
```

What is the reason for different scraping results? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Log is different for the code below:

```
function testx(){
  var api_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=STOCHF&symbol=rxt&interval=daily&fastkperiod=5&apikey=1L5DUZ4F711436KC";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);
  var res = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log("res2 = " + res);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using as well as the custom function? How does your custom formula look like? Also, which API are you using?

Comment: I've added the code. Initially, it worked just fine. Later it started producing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is a duplicate

You can find the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524370/google-script-for-alphavantage-gives-weird-results)

### Solution

Your `fetch` request needs to constain `{validateHttpsCertificates: false})` like this:

```js
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url, {validateHttpsCertificates: false});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I worked just like magic! I searched few times, but unfortunately, I didn't find that post. Do I need to delete this post now?

Comment: No  problem :). No, just keep the post, it's fine, one of the admins will know what to do with it :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. :)